# Как подключить таблицу стилей LESS в *.aspx странице?

Tags: css, less

Пробовал как для обычного CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="App_Themes/DefaultTheme/Main.less"/>
```

Такой подход не дает никаких результатов, стили не видны элементам страницы.

Как сделать правильное подключение LESS?

Comment: Использование LESS [вот здесь посмотри](http://aschikov.ru/less-css-rukovodstvo-dlya-nachinayushhix.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что less - это не css. Тип по умолчанию - `text/css`.

В принципе, можно попробовать сделать

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" ...
```

но, скорее всего, браузеры проигнорируют и это.

*Надо компилировать less на сервере и подключать к странице скомпилированный css-файл.*